# automatically update Arcmap attribute when updatin Excel table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel

I have a map in arcmap where i want to display information that contains values that will probably change every year. 
I would rather not having to remove joins and then join my new excel sheet every year. Is there a way:

1. To directly link my excel sheet to asrcmap so that my map would be modified upon the excel modification
2. As my excel numbers would change based on a multiplication factor, is there a way to save the formula in the attribute table so that my values would automatically change when i input the new multiplication factor into arcmap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.